# AzCopy list - How to show name list file without another info

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I want to create variable from `azcopy list` output.
but the output will show like this :

```
INFO: KeyPointTips.pdf; Content Length: 98.29 KiB
```

Is there a way to make the output from the `azcopy list` only showing the file name and format, without any other information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's always with the same convention you can retrieve the file name with regex or with simple splits:

```
$azOutput = "INFO: KeyPointTips.pdf; Content Length: 98.29 KiB"

$fileName = $azOutput.Split(':')[1].Split(';')[0].Trim()

Write-Host $fileName 
# KeyPointTips.pdf
```

Comment: While this works (as long as no file name contains `;`), can we agree this situation is ridiculous? What where the authors of `azcopy list` thinking?